# REGEX: seperate colon with comma (IP:PORT)

Tags: regex

I am struggling with converting this string

```
date,time,mac_address,source_ip:source_port,dst_ip:dst_port,method,url  

2017-04-01,00:01:03,00:10:f3:3f:fe:f2,192.168.2.62:28741,172.20.0:80,GET,http://www.website.com
```

to

```
2017-04-01,00:01:03,00:10:f3:3f:fe:f2,192.168.2.62,28741,172.20.0,80,GET,http://www.website.com
```

(separating ip:port) for hours but I couldn't figure it out! tried regex like `(?:\.\d+)(?<=\d)\:` but it doesn't work.
I want to use powershell `-replace` operator.

Comment: `\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+(:)\d+` matches (and captures) the `:` that's between the IP and the port. Does this help?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried that since the text files are large log file it makes the process longer!

Comment: @MarounMaroun In powershell it matches all ip:port and i can't use replace operator

Comment: You appear to be parsing some sort of CSV data. If that's the case, you might have a better change using a dedicated tool or library.

Comment: I kinda hope it'll be like this : `"string" -replace "regex" , ","`

Comment: Well, your input string is a bit strange since there are 3 or 4 IP parts. Usually, there are 4. See my latest answer edit, it will account for 3 or 4 part IPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
$s = "2017-04-01,00:01:03,00:10:f3:3f:fe:f2,192.168.2.62:28741,172.20.0:80,GET,http://www.website.com"
$s -replace "(\d+(?:\.\d+){2,3}):(\d+,)", '$1,$2'
```

The output:

```
2017-04-01,00:01:03,00:10:f3:3f:fe:f2,192.168.2.62,28741,172.20.0,80,GET,http://www.website.com
```

Here,

- `(\d+(?:\.\d+){2,3})` - matches 1+ digits followed with 2 or 3 occurrences of a `.` followed with 1+ digits (Group 1, `$1`)
- `:` - a colon
- `(\d+,)` - 1+ digits and a `,` (Group 2, `$2`)